# JQuery ajax success scope

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have this line of code :

```
$.ajax({
    url: "ViewQuiz.aspx/SetAllQuestionsByQuizId",
    type: "POST",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: 'json',
    data: "{'quizId':'" + quizId + "'}",
    success: function (data) {
        htmlString += '<select class="inputTextStyle selectAnswerToQuestion">';
        $.map(data.d, function (item) {
            htmlString += '<option value="' + item.QuestionId + '">' + item.QuestionContent + '</option>';

        });
        htmlString += '</select>';


    },
    error: function (result) {

    }

});

return htmlString;
```

the `htmlString` is returning nothing. 
although if I `console.log` the `item`, its returning my objects.

why ?

Comment: add some console stmt in "error" function and verify if it is not failing.

Comment: its entering the "success" , and returning my results properly.

Comment: You can't return from an async function like that.

Comment: The JSON you are sending is invalid.

Comment: @adeneo: I was looking for the same question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ajax means Asynchronous execution, control will move further once the request is made.It wont wait for return of ajax call.
In your example Ajax call will be made and when control reaches to `return` statement `success` function may/may not been executed so its returning nothing.
You should do the required things in `success` function itself.

```
success: function (data) {
        //...........
        htmlString += '</select>';
        // Do the required things here instead of returning `htmlString`

    },
```

Realted question [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-to-return-the-response-from-an-ajax-call)